# Gulp: How to implement livereload without Chrome's livereload plugin?

Tags: gulp, gulp-livereload

It looks like [`gulp-livereload`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-livereload) requires [Chrome's livereload plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) to work.

Is there a way to implement livereload that doesn't require any browser plugin, and will work in all browsers?

Any examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How I've missed that.

You should add the `livereload` script in your `index.html`, and change the port to which you're currently using.

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

You may want to inject this only on a development version, so I think you should have a look to **[gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject)** to get this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! Adding this script solved the problem. Could you just clarify where `livereload.js` is coming from? Is it available at `localhost:35729` because of `livereload.listen()` in the `gulpfile.js`? Also, what `snipver=1` does? (the docs are not clear)

Comment: Indeed this script is available through the `gulp-livereload` plugin, for the `snipver`, you should have a look to [this link](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js), which explain it well